# Streaming a csv file to a console application -Whats going wrong(grpc)?

Tags: c#, .net, grpc, minimal-apis, .net-7.0

So i got this grpc client that streams data from a csv to a console and just prints it,
in 1 minute it can do about 1.5mil records.
On the other hand i got this minimal api, Now here begins the problem
Im guessing I need to use httpclient to make the call inorder to compare?
Because before i had this:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
await foreach (var line in MakeHttpCall())
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

And this was twice as fast , 3 million records in a minute then I figured out I'm testing it wrong,
However how do i use a client and what method I need to invoke in the foreach?

```
  async IAsyncEnumerable<string> MakeHttpCall()
{
    var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    int Count = 0;

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\kosta\source\repos\gRPCDemoUsingNET6\gRPCDemoUsingNET6\Data\sales_records.csv"))
    {
        while (watch.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60) && !reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(';');
            yield return line;
            Count++;
        }

    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Stream ended: Total Records:{Count.ToString()} in {watch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes} minutes and {watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} seconds.");
}
```

How do I procced? Obviously I'm doing smth/multiple things wrong.
If i try to do smth like this

```
 await foreach (var line in client.GetAsync(""))
```

I get a "does not contain extension definition for getasyncenumarator

Comment: Your use case isn't clear to me. When you say "_each line as it is being recieved_", does that mean you expect the API to send each line one at a time? If so, your API code doesn't seem to do that. Actually, I'm a bit confused about your API code anyway, as the API call itself calls a `MakeHttpCall` method that you didn't show, and then you have an isolated piece of code that reads a CSV file, and saves the first line and that line split into a variable. It ignores the rest of the file and doesn't do anything with the line it read. Please clarify your question

Comment: Yeah I dont know what to do with the line, how to i return the values to the Ui?
I do want the api to send each line at at time to the frontend and im unsure how to do it

Comment: What do you mean by "one at a time"? You can read the whole file in one go, why would you want to send the lines out individually?

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel im doing a grpc comparison with webapi, streaming the data as it comes in.
Anyways changed the question

Comment: The best way is to read into a buffer that take current content of receive data.  Than read only line at a time from buffer.  Remove line from buffer as you proceed.  Check if buffer contains a return.  When you do not have a return in the buffer read the http connection and append to current buffer.

Comment: Can you show code example?